# Resize frame layout when setting toolbar visibility to gone?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the following layout in which I replace the FrameLayout listContainer with a Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appTitle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_title_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTitleFont"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_view_panes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/listContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/saveCancelBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/save_cancel_bar_height"
            android:background="@color/fluxx_blue"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/editorCancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@color/fluxx_blue"
                android:text="@string/editor_cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/editorSaveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/fluxx_blue"
                android:text="@string/editor_save"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment requires hiding the toolbar. I call setVisibility(View.GONE) on the toolbar in the fragment's onResume() method, as I also want to hide it when navigating to the fragment via a back press. However, when I hide the toolbar, my fragment does not take up the entire screen. Presumably this is because I remove the toolbar and it shifts everything up by the height of the toolbar. However, my FrameLayout has layout_weight of 1, which I thought would ensure that it stretches to fill the screen. How can make sure it resizes?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute to the `LinearLayout` below your disappeared toolbar.

Not to the embedded one.